# how to use egrep regex?

Tags: bash, grep

how to use egrep regex ?

```
source
exec pro..do_pr_ddd_sum 123039246, 995, 201705848

egrep '*pr_ddd_sum*123039246*995*' *
-- no result found
```

In the code above, it can't get any result back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean `'pr_ddd_sum.*123039246.*995'`.

Comment: I changed to this : '.*pr_ddd_sum.*123039246.*995.*', works. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. That should also do, but unless you specifically anchor the regex to the end and the beginning, you don't *need* leading and trailing `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing shell wildcards with regular expression metacharacters.  In the shell, a "*" means any character.  In a regex, this metacharacter means zero or more of the preceding character.  Look at Michael's suggestion.  In it, the dot ('.') stands for any character, so '.*' means any character followed by zero or more repetitions of any character.